# Place a JPG into JInternalFrame

Tags: jinternalframe

I  want to place JPGs into frames (scrollable).

I tried to modify this: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/multipleFrames.html

My code doesn't put the picture into the frame.

```
// THIS CALLS STATIC IMPORT DECLARATIONS

// THESE THREE IMPORTS ARE NEEDED FOR BUILDING THE FRAMES AND DESK
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

// THESE IMPORTS ARE NEEDED FOR THE GRAPHICS (BUFFEREDIMAGE)
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

// THIS SETS THE TITLE OF THE PROGRAM AND OPENS THE PROGRAM
class Scratch {

// THIS SETS THE MAIN METHOD
public static void main (String args []) {

// THIS LOADS THE FIRST IMAGE

BufferedImage image1 = null;
try {
    image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("scan0001.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) { 
   e.printStackTrace();
}


Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
JImagePanel imagePanel1 = new JImagePanel(image1,0,0);
imagePanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight()));
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane1.setSize(100,100);
scrollPane1.getViewport().add(imagePanel1);
JPanel topPanel1 = new JPanel();
topPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
topPanel1.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);



// THIS BUILDS THE DESKTOP IN WHICH TO PLACE THE INTERNAL FRAMES
JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();

// THIS BUILDS THE BIG (MAIN) FRAME AND SETS THE TITLE
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Big Frame");

// THIS ALLOWS BIG (MAIN) FRAME TO CLOSE AND RETURN TO CMD PROMPT
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// THIS SETS THE SIZE OF THE BIG (MAIN) FRAME
frame.setSize(600,400);

// THIS SETS THE LOCATION OF THE BIG (MAIN) FRAME ON THE SCREEN
frame.setLocation(100,100);

// THIS MAKES THE BIG (MAIN) FRAME VISIBLE
frame.setVisible(true);

// THIS BUILDS THE INTERNAL FRAMES
JInternalFrame frame1 = new JInternalFrame("Frame 1", true, true, true, true);

// THIS SETS LOCATION AND SIZE
frame1.setBounds(20,200,150,100);

// THIS MAKES THE INTERNAL FRAMES VISIBLE
frame1.setVisible(true);

// THIS PLACES THE JINTERNALFRAME ONTO THE DESKTOP
desk.add(frame1);

// THIS ADDS THE DESKTOP TO THE BIG (MAIN) FRAME
frame.add(desk);

class JImagePanel extends JPanel { 

private BufferedImage image1;
int x, y;
public JImagePanel(BufferedImage image1, int x, int y){
super();
this.image1 = image1;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
}
}


// THESE ARE NEEDED TO CLOSE THE PROGRAM

}
}
```